# SIGABRT error when I delete (while in the edit mode) a new row that was just added from another nav view DidChangeObject

Tags: iphone

I have a table populated with core data and when I press the add button it loads a new navigation view where I can enter data and save the new object.

When the object is added in core data, the view is popped out and it goes back to the table where the new row is added at the right place (order alphabetically) with the right information.

This is where my problem happens. When I try to delete the row that was just added, I get the SIGABRT. If I go to any other navigation views and come back to delete the same row, it works.

From what I understand, the row is either non existent right after creation when it gets deleted or it gets deleted twice.

I can delete it after going anywhere else in the app but it only crashes when I delete it right after being created.

I put [self.tableView reloadData]; in the viewWillAppear and it doesn't seem to do anything.

I have tried Zombies, debugger, NSLog, and a lot of other technique to pin point where the app crash and all I get is the dreaded and hard to pin point SIGABRT.

My commitEditingStyle function is pretty much like the standart one and when I debug with breakmarks, I know the error happens right after or inside the didChangeObject

I know this function works

```
[self deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:YES];
```

and then right after it crashes.

Thanks for all the help

Answer (score 1):

In your datasource, you have to return one row less after your deleteRows-method than before. I don't think you delete a row in your datasource at all, am I right?

So, for example

1. dataSource returns 3 rows in 1st section
2. deleteRows...-method
3. dataSource returns 2 rows in 1st section

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for such a fast answer.

My error had to do with the nav controller releasing a view from the stack too early or too late.

I think I spent about 15 hours on this...